# I can't create a "trap" block

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

So, I am trying to make a "trap" block. It should kill the entity that will stand on it(or walk as in the code, if somebody knows how to make that it will do something while an entity stands on it, it will be helpful). Here's the code for the block:

```
package com.daniel_sl.blocks;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLiving;


public class Trap extends Block{

  public boolean isDead;

  protected Trap(Material material) {
    super(material);
  }

  public void setDead()
  {
    this.isDead = true;
  }

  public void onEntityWalking(Entity Entity){
    if(Entity instanceof EntityLiving){

      Entity.setDead();
    }
  }
}
```

When I stand on the block it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a typing error.
I would write the method of the method as follows:

```
public void onEntityWalking(Entity entity){
  if(entity instanceof EntityLiving){
      entity.setDead();
  }
}
```